# IntelliJ collapsing single line methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, intellij-14, intellij-15

Since I've updated my version of intelliJ (14.x to 15.x) it has started automatically collapsing single line methods in the `Java` editor:

Previous version:

```
public void setContext(SecurityContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Latest version:

```
public void setContext(SecurityContext context) { this.context = context; }
```

Is there a way to prevent this?  I find the original version much easier on the eyes!

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it formats this code, it just collapses it. When you look on the left border of the code view, there should be a small "+" sign to expand it, like for the `import` block.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll change the wording of the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: See duplicate: [*IntelliJ IDEA one-line function formatting*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36294708/642706)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Open 'Settings' from the File menu. Under 'Editor' -> 'General' -> 'Code Folding', you will find a 'Collapse by Default' section.

Simply uncheck 'One-line methods' and click OK.

[image]

Comment: this will also work if you put an opening brace in new line and want to fold it to `{...}` instead of `latest version` of question

Comment: One thing to note : You'll have to re-open the file for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Update: for newer versions of IJ uncheck: 
File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding | Java | One line methods

Answer (score 11):

On Windows:

**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Code Folding** -> Uncheck "One-line methods"

Answer (score 2):

For mac,
Code > Folding > Expand ALL/To Level

Comment: There doesn't seem to be such a path; the other answer works on Mac.