# IntelliJ IDEA one-line function formatting

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ keeps formatting this:

```java
public void addElement(Element elem) {
    this.elements.add(elem);
}
```

into this:

```java
public void addElement(Element elem) { this.elements.add(elem); }
```

I prefer the multi-line formatting. How can I tell this to IntelliJ? I have unchecked the following boxes in Settings -> Editor -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces

- Control statements in one line
- Simple blocks in one line
- Simple methods in one line

Didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ collapsing single line methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995083/intellij-collapsing-single-line-methods)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I suspect that your IntelliJ is not actually changing the actual file, but instead, visually collapsing one line methods in the display.

To have IntelliJ not change the display of one line methods, look at:

Preferences (or Settings), Editor, General, Code Folding, Collapse by default, One-line methods

[image]

Comment: You will have to reopen the file(s) to see the effect.

Comment: It's settings now, not preferences. (May just be the difference between mac and windows, I am on windows)

Comment: It remains "Preferences" on the Mac ;-)

Comment: I didn't have to `Refresh`

Comment: Op was looking for formatting, which changes structure. Folding is for presentation in the editor gui and does not format the single line annotation/decorator as desired.

Comment: for the opposite effect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081326/reformat-a-one-line-method-to-a-single-line-of-text-in-intellij

Comment: @Draculater When I asked the question I thought it was doing formatting. I didn't realize at the time this was just for presentation. This answer solves the issue I had.

Comment: @Draculater, Intellij won't rewrite the actual multi line method to a one line method in the file. I suspect Intellij is just reformatting the presentation of the file, so I stand behind my answer.

Answer (score 120):

below is the shortcut for Merge multiple lines into a line -

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: This saved me a lot of trouble

Comment: This should be the top answer if this question was for a quick way to do it.

Comment: @MacintoshFan the original question is how to stop intellij from collapsing multiple lines into one line, which I suspect is just happening in the display of the file for the author of the question. This answer is how to collapse multiple lines into one line in the actual file. Also, this answer doesn't work in my Intellij v2021 on a Mac.

Comment: It works just fine for me: latest macOS and IntelliJ.