# How to disable different-background-color-for-braces mouseover thing in IntelliJ IDEA Java projects?

Tags: intellij-idea

Why is IntelliJ making a different background colour for braces here in this Java project, that shows me a mouseover of the whole function?

How do I get it to simply stop displaying the different background colour, while keeping the mouseover feature, or if not possible, just disabling both?

[image: Different Background Color for Braces]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35995083/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36294708/3001761

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings/General scroll down to Highlight matched brace.

Comment: That probably just highlights the matched brace corresponding to one that the cursor is on.